# How can I replace comma with dot in arrays of strings in python?

Tags: python

[Array of strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpWg0.png)

Hi, I have this array of strings but I can't convert it in an array of floats, I think because of the comma. So there is a way to convert comma in dot or convert directly arrays of strings in an array of floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try replacing the comma with period and then casting:

```py
df["col"] = df["col"].str.replace(',', '.', regex=False).astype(float)
```

Comment: It gives me this error:                  *** IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Do you have any missing values in your column?  If so, how do you want to handle them?

Comment: You have, of course, to replace the `"col"` with the index-name of your column. Depending on your picture i quess it would be `0` (without quotes because it looks like you use interger index)

Comment: But you should provide a sample of your data in code (what is it, a pandas DataFrame oder Numpy-Array?). Its not clear solely from the picture

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're dealing with a 1D array named `arr`:

```py
new_arr = np.array([float(elem.replace(',', '.')) for elem in arr])
```

Or:

```py
new_arr = np.char.replace(arr, ',', '.').astype(float)
```